# Visual Studio 2013 UI crashes

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

From time to time my Visual Studio 2013 Professional will lose its color scheme on application startup and will become something like this:

[image]

Which makes code impossible/very unpleasant to read.

It seems like the application theme just gets broken so I've tried fixing it by going to Tools -> Options -> Change Theme, but no luck there.

The only way right now is to reboot my PC, but was hoping if there is any other solution?

Comment: looks funny. Do you have any extensions installed?

Comment: Real programmers code white on white... in notepad. You just need to get better at being a codinger

Comment: @Joel yeah, Postsharp, Resharper, TeamCity

Comment: @musefan if in your opinion by being more productive using VS you become a bad codinger then there is not much I can add ;)

Comment: I hope musefan is not serious at all. @inside: my uneducated guess is that an extension caused this strange behavior. I would try to disable them and see if the error is gone. I would start with Postsharp.

Comment: it's extremely hard to reproduce, happens once every couple weeks :(